# Get records where all the corresponding columns of the same column is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

My data looks like this

```
| id             | Failure            
+----------------+-----------
| 1              | null 
| 1              | null  
| 1              | null  
| 1              | abc  
| 1              | null  
| 2              | null
| 2              | null  
| 2              | null  
| 2              | abc  
| 2              | null
| 3              | null
| 3              | null  
| 3              | null  
| 3              | null  
| 3              | null
```

Now I need to get the id when all the failure column data has null for that id.

Expected result:

```
| id             | Failure            
+----------------+----------
| 3              | null
| 3              | null  
| 3              | null  
| 3              | null  
| 3              | null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Select * 
    from Table 
    where Id not in (select id from Table where failure is not null)
```

Comment: Hi! While this may be an answer to the question (untested), code only answers are discouraged on SO. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer to help OP better understand, and to provide greater benefit to future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the ids, use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having max(failure) is null;
```

I don't see a reason to get all the repetitive rows.  If you want them, then I suggest `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.failure is not null
                 );
```

Comment: i actually need the count of distinct field id above query is not giving count

Comment: @KalyanVarma . . . Nothing in this question refers to a count.  If you have another question, you should ask it as a *new* question (if you change this one, you may invalidate answers).